# Java - error checking using abstract superclass or not? [homework related]

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract, extends

first off I wanna mention this is assignment related. I'm having trouble understanding some parts and failed to find any information to answer my question.

so I have two classes: one called RecursivePascal, one called IterativePascal.
I also have an interface Pascal which both of those implementation classes implement.

Now I have an assignment to create an abstract class ErrorPascal that implements
the Pascal interface, and both the implementation classes
should extend ErrorPascal.

I'm supposed to add basic sanity checking to the parameters
of printPascal and binom (both these methods exist in both IterativePascal and RecursivePascal)
and to try to avoid duplicate code

My question is: **what's the point of the abstract superclass in this situation? Is there some way I can
do the sanity checking in that class for both implementation classes?
If so, how is it done? If not, what is the point of the abstract superclass at all in this case?**

Comment: See this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/106601/in-simple-words-what-are-are-the-purposes-of-abstract-classes-and-or-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A super class, abstract or not, allows you to define methods there that can be used by classes extending it - or any caller, really.

In your case, you might have a `checkSomeParam(...)` method that both RecursivePascal and IterativePascal call. Rather than duplicating that method in both classes, you place it in the super class.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense, I was trying to do something completely different. Thank you, I think that answers my question, will mark as answer when possible.